# How to change a pixel distance to meters?

Tags: coordinates

I have a .bmp image with a map. What i know:

1. Height an Width of bmp image
2. dpi
3. Map Scale
4. Image Center's coordinates in meters.

What i want:

1. How can i calculate some points of image (for example corners) in meters.
2. Or how can i change a pixel distanse to meters?

What i do before:

For sure i know image center coordinates in pixels:

```
CenterXpix = Widht/2;
CenterYpix = Height/2;
```

But what i gonna do to find another corners coordinates. Don't think that:

```
metersDistance = pixelDistance*Scale;
```

is a correct equation.

Any advises?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the height or width in both meters and pixels, you can calculate the scale in meters/pixel. You equation:

```
metersDistance = pixelDistance*Scale;
```

is correct, but only if your points are on the same axis. If your two points are diagonal from each other, you have to use good old pythagoras (in pseudocode):

```
X = XdistancePix*scale;
Y = YdistancePix*scale;

Distance_in_m = sqrt(X*X+Y*Y);
```